# React Native Autocomplete Input results list ignores touch

Tags: react-native

I've been tackling this issue for a few weeks, and it's driving me insane.

Basically, I have a `Modal` component that nests a form. The form is a bunch of `TextInput` components, at the heart of everything. One of the components in the form is an `Autocomplete`, from [React Native Autocomplete Input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-autocomplete-input). The problem is that I'm able to put the results list from `Autocomplete` in front of everything else, but my touches pass right through the container and focuses on the `TextInput` behind the results list. I'm not able to change the order of components, so I can't just put this one input after everything else.

The general setup of the form is below:

```js
<Modal>
 <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
   <View style={containerStyle}>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
     <View>
       <CardSection style={sectionStyle}>
          <Input
            ...props...
          />
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection style={acSectionStyle}>
          <Text style={labelStyle}>Brand *</Text>
            <View style={acContainerStyle}>
            <Autocomplete
              autoCapitalize='none'
              autoCorrect={false}
              listStyle={acListStyle}
              data={brands.length === 1 && comp(query, brands[0]) ? [] : brands}
              defaultValue={query}
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
              renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
              hideResults={this.state.hideResults ? this.state.hideResults : undefined}
              onBlur={() => this.setState({ hideResults: true })}
              onFocus={() => this.setState({ hideResults: false })}
            />
          </View>
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection style={sectionStyle}>
          <Input
           ...props...
          />
        </CardSection>
   </View>
   </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  </View>
 </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</Modal>
```

I had to stack the `TouchableWithoutFeedback` components in order to make the modal behave. There's more props in the components, but I only kept what was relevant.

My `renderItem` method is:

```js
renderItem(brand) {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ width: '100%', height: 25 }}
        onPress={() => {
          this.setState({ pBrand: brand.trim(), query: brand.trim() });
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.listItemStyle}>{brand}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
```

I don't believe it's a styling issue, but I've added the styles that deal with `zIndex` just in case:

```js
containerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
    position: 'relative',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    zIndex: 1
  },
acSectionStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    zIndex: 2,
    height: 40
  },
  acContainerStyle: {
    right: 0,
    width: '75%',
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 2
  }
```

The default `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` for `Autocomplete` is `always`. All of the questions I've seen suggest to set a higher `zIndex` (which isn't a problem - I can *see* the list, but if I tap on it, the tap goes through to the `TextInput` behind it), change the order of components (which I can't do), set [onStartShouldSetResponderCapture](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html#capture-shouldset-handlers) to `true` (which didn't work), or mess with [Pointer Events](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#pointerevents), none of which worked. 
I'm using React Native V0.57.1, an actual Android device, and the project is built with Expo.

Finally, I've recorded a small demo for what my problem is. When the cursor re-appears, that's when I clicked on a result.

[image: Showing how the tap goes through the top view]

Is there just something I'm missing? I've only been writing in React Native for a few months so that's a definite possibility. I come from a web development background, so I thought that if a component was on top (thanks to `zIndex`), I'd be able to tap on it and not through it by default.

Edit: While messing around, if I change `acSectionStyle` to a height big enough for the dropdown, then the dropdown works how it should. The issue comes in when a sibling `CardSection` is being covered. The other `CardSection` takes precedence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally found a workaround. Whether it's correct or not, which I feel like it isn't, at least it works!
I ended up taking the `Autocomplete` component (along with its' view) outside of the `CardSection`, but leaving the label in it, like so:

```js
<CardSection style={acSectionStyle}>
          <Text style={labelStyle}>Brand *</Text>
        </CardSection>
        <View style={acContainerStyle}>
            <Autocomplete
              autoCorrect={false}
              listStyle={acListStyle}
              // Text input container
              inputContainerStyle={acTextContainerStyle}
              style={acTextStyle}
              placeholder='China Glaze'
              data={brands.length === 1 && comp(query, brands[0]) ? [] : brands}
              defaultValue={query}
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
              renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
              hideResults={this.state.hideResults ? this.state.hideResults : undefined}
              onBlur={() => this.setState({ hideResults: true })}
              onFocus={() => this.setState({ hideResults: false })}
            />
          </View>
```

Then, and this is the part I think is wrong, I just played with the `absolute`-positioned view until I moved it far enough down to line up next to the label:

```js
 labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    flex: 1
  },
 acContainerStyle: {
    right: 0,
    top: 102,
    width: '72%',
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 10
  }
```

I would *love* if someone has a better solution, but this is the best I could come up with. I try to avoid moving views with hard coded values just for scaling purposes, but it seems like this is the only option.